# How can I add a pre-loader to an existing complex flash project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preloader

I have a pretty complex flash project that I need to add a pre-loader to.

Currently all the items we have are in the Library inside the .fla file. I've been reading a few of the pre-loader blog entries and tutorials and getting nowhere.

I've tried to create another .fla file that loads the compiled .swf file of the complex project and that did not work as well.

This is my first flash project and I'm pretty inexperienced with it. What do I need to do?

Do I have to strip all the items from the library and load them individually (and have them saved somewhere on a server) ?

How can I create a loader class within the project that runs on Frame 1 and "Loads" all the items that are needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make a loader class within the existing project that loads everything in the first frame if needed.  Its pretty dirty design-wise, but can work.

Comment: How would I do that? I found some classes that supposedly do that but when I simulated a download it just waited for a few sec and then traced 100% and the game started.

Comment: quite a few tutorials out there.  I prefer using some kind of loading graphic as well on games to tell the user why they might be waiting.  The last time I had to dig up a good tutorial on it, I think I refered to http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3preloader/ - needs a few tweaks, but try it out.  You'll need to modify it for multiple assets, but start out with one so that its easy to compute bytesleft to d/l out of bytestotal